# How to sort ascending and descending depending on a value in another column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with a a set of values (prices). Within each group of `initiator_id` I need to sort prices ascending if the `type == sell`, and descending if the `type == buy`.
Then I add an id within each group. Right now I do:

```py
 df['bidnum'] = df.groupby(['initiator_id', 'type']).cumcount()
```

What is the efficient way to sort ascending within each group `'initiator_id', 'type == sell'` and descending for `'initiator_id', 'type == buy'` ?

Here is how the original dataset looks like now:

```
initiator_id    price   type    bidnum
1       170.81  sell    0
2       170.81  sell    0
2       169.19  buy     0
3       170.81  sell    0
3       169.19  buy     0
3       70.81   sell    1
4       170.81  sell    0
4       169.19  buy     0
4       70.81   sell    1
4       69.19   buy     1
```

and I need something like:

```
initiator_id, price, type
1, 100,sell
1, 99, sell
1, 98, sell
1, 110, buy
1, 120, buy
1, 125, buy
```

So that `sell` subgroup within each `initiator_id` group is sorted descending, and `buy` subgroup is sorted ascending.

Comment: show your source raw CSV input text and expected raw CSV output text. it is easier to work with than dataframe format.

Comment: @Joshua sorry, my bad, just fixed that

Comment: so you want the sell always above buy for each id? so it's like: `id1 sell, id1 buy, id2 sell, id2 buy, id3 sell, id3 buy` ?

Comment: btw, your expected output shows descending sell and ascending buy. but your requirements say ascending sell and descending buy. so can i assume your expected output is correct and your requirements are wrong?

Comment: "our expected output is correct and your requirements are wrong?" - yes, you are right, but it doesn't matter so much: if I'd known one way it's easy to do the opposite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can assume that your `"price"` column will always contain non-negative values, we could "cheat". Assign a negative value to the prices of buy or sell operations, sort, and then calculate the absolute value to go back to the original prices:

1. If type is `"buy"`, the price remains positive (2 * 1 - 1 = 1). If type is `"sell"`, the price will become negative (2 * 0 - 1 = -1).

   ```
   df["price"] = df["price"] * (2 * (df["type"] == "buy").astype(int) - 1)
   ```
2. Now sort values normally. I've included both `"initiator_id"` and `"type"` columns to match your expected output:

   ```
   df = df.sort_values(["initiator_id", "type", "price"])
   ```
3. Finally, calculate the absolute value of the `"price"` column to retrieve your original values:

   ```
   df["price"] = df["price"].abs()
   ```

Expected output of this operation on your sample input:

```
   initiator_id   price  type  bidnum
0             1  170.81  sell       0
2             2  169.19   buy       0
1             2  170.81  sell       0
4             3  169.19   buy       0
3             3  170.81  sell       0
5             3   70.81  sell       1
9             4   69.19   buy       1
7             4  169.19   buy       0
6             4  170.81  sell       0
8             4   70.81  sell       1
```

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Comments added to describe how this solution works as it could be used in other more general contexts.

One solution:

```
final_df = pd.DataFrame()
grouped_df = df.groupby(['initiator_id', 'type'])

for key, item in grouped_df:
    # the dfg are the different 'subgroups' created by groupby
    # reset_index create a dataframe object from the groupby object so that we can
    #    append the subgroups after sorting them 
    # could also use item instead of get_group(key)
    dfg = grouped_df.get_group(key).reset_index()
    # the subgroups are sorted according to the value of the first cell in the 
    #   'type' column (by construction there is a unique value in this column) 
    orderg = (dfg.loc[0, 'type']=='buy')  # ascending order if type = buy
    final_df = final_df.append(dfg.sort_values('price', ascending=orderg))

# some cosmetics to arrive to the final df            
final_df.drop(final_df.columns[0], axis=1, inplace=True)
final_df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
```

Output:

```
   initiator_id   price  type
0             1  170.81  sell
1             2  169.19   buy
2             2  170.81  sell
3             3  169.19   buy
4             3  170.81  sell
5             3   70.81  sell
6             4   69.19   buy
7             4  169.19   buy
8             4  170.81  sell
9             4   70.81  sell
```

Answer (score 0):

Everyone else gave a solution with pandas. Here I present a solution without pandas.

The input CSV:

```
initiator_id,price,type,bidnum
1,170.81,sell,0
2,170.81,sell,0
2,169.19,buy,0
3,170.81,sell,0
3,169.19,buy,0
3,70.81,sell,1
4,170.81,sell,0
4,169.19,buy,0
4,70.81,sell,1
4,69.19,buy,1
```

The output CSV:

```
initiator_id,price,type,bidnum
1,170.81,sell,0
2,170.81,sell,0
2,169.19,buy,0
3,170.81,sell,0
3,70.81,sell,1
3,169.19,buy,0
4,170.81,sell,0
4,70.81,sell,1
4,69.19,buy,1
4,169.19,buy,0
```

The code:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import numpy

"""
the reason why this code uses exec is so that the ordering of columns can be arbitrary
"""

def remove_duplicates(seq):
    seen = set()
    seen_add = seen.add
    return [x for x in seq if not (x in seen or seen_add(x))]

def returnLastIndex(temp2):
    global mydict
    temp3 = mydict['initiator_id'][temp2]
    while True:
        temp2 = temp2 + 1
        try:
            if mydict['initiator_id'][temp2] != temp3:
                return temp2-1
        except:
            return temp2-1

def returnFirstIndex(temp2):
    global mydict
    temp3 = mydict['initiator_id'][temp2]
    while temp2 >= 1:
        temp2 = temp2 - 1
        if mydict['initiator_id'][temp2] != temp3:
            return temp2+1
    return 0


with open("input.csv") as file:
    lines = file.readlines()

new_lines = []
new_headers = []
for x in range(len(lines)): #loop to reamove headers and newlines
    if x == 0:
        for y in lines[x].strip().split(","):
            new_headers.append(y)
    else:
        new_lines.append(lines[x].strip())

mydict = OrderedDict()
for x in new_headers:
    exec("mydict['"+x+"'] = []")

for x in range(len(new_headers)):
    for y in new_lines:
        if new_headers[x] == "initiator_id":
            exec("mydict['"+new_headers[x]+"'].append(int('"+y.split(",")[x]+"'))")
        elif new_headers[x] == "price":
            exec("mydict['"+new_headers[x]+"'].append(float('"+y.split(",")[x]+"'))")
        else:
            exec("mydict['"+new_headers[x]+"'].append('"+y.split(",")[x]+"')")

for x in new_headers:
    exec("mydict['"+x+"'] = numpy.array(mydict['"+x+"'])")


temp1 = mydict['initiator_id'].argsort()

for x in (new_headers):
    exec("mydict['"+x+"'] = mydict['"+x+"'][temp1]")

splice_list_first = []

for x in range(len(mydict['initiator_id'])):
    splice_list_first.append(returnFirstIndex(x))

splice_list_last = []

for x in range(len(mydict['initiator_id'])):
    splice_list_last.append(returnLastIndex(x))

splice_list_first = remove_duplicates(splice_list_first)
splice_list_last = remove_duplicates(splice_list_last)

master_string = ",".join(new_headers)+"\n"

for x in range(len(splice_list_first)):
    temp4 = OrderedDict()
    for y in new_headers:
        exec("temp4['"+y+"'] = mydict['"+y+"']["+str(splice_list_first[x])+":"+str(splice_list_last[x]+1)+"]")
    sell_index = []
    buy_index = []
    for z in range(len(temp4['type'])):
        if temp4['type'][z] == "sell":
            sell_index.append(z)
        if temp4['type'][z] == "buy":
            buy_index.append(z)
    temp5 = OrderedDict()
    for a in range(len(sell_index)):
        for b in new_headers:
            try:
                exec("temp5['"+b+"']")
            except:
                exec("temp5['"+b+"'] = []")
            exec("temp5['"+b+"'].append(temp4['"+b+"']["+str(sell_index[a])+":"+str(sell_index[a]+1)+"][0])")
    try:
        for c in new_headers:
            exec("temp5['"+c+"'] = numpy.array(temp5['"+c+"'])")
        temp7 = temp5['price'].argsort()[::-1]
        for d in (new_headers):
            exec("temp5['"+d+"'] = temp5['"+d+"'][temp7]")
        for e in range(len(temp5['initiator_id'])):
            for f in new_headers:
                master_string = master_string + str(temp5[f][e])+","
            master_string = master_string[:-1]+"\n"
    except Exception as g:
        pass


    temp6 = OrderedDict()
    for a in range(len(buy_index)):
        for b in new_headers:
            try:
                exec("temp6['"+b+"']")
            except:
                exec("temp6['"+b+"'] = []")
            exec("temp6['"+b+"'].append(temp4['"+b+"']["+str(buy_index[a])+":"+str(buy_index[a]+1)+"][0])")
    try:
        for c in new_headers:
            exec("temp6['"+c+"'] = numpy.array(temp6['"+c+"'])")
        temp7 = temp6['price'].argsort()
        for d in (new_headers):
            exec("temp6['"+d+"'] = temp6['"+d+"'][temp7]")
        for e in range(len(temp6['initiator_id'])):
            for f in new_headers:
                master_string = master_string + str(temp6[f][e])+","
            master_string = master_string[:-1]+"\n"
    except Exception as g:
        pass


print(master_string)
f = open("output.csv", "w")
f.write(master_string)
f.close()
```